# c# how to thread a windows form

Tags: c#

I have a method that creates a bound with a windows form and also sents to that window form a parameter. I would like to create a thread to that window form. How can I do it?

```
public Send_to_windowForm(string name_form, string value_for_labellBox)
{
thread t = new thread(new threadStart (form(value_for_labelBox)).Start();
 Application.Run(new form(value_for_labelBox)); 
form.text=name_form;
}
```

it's not working. I don't think it's correct. How can I do it? And one more question: how can i handleall the form application that the thread opens? I would like to handle all the forms because in a specific moment  i want to add a new value to one of the forms opened on the desktop.

THX

Comment: Can't you simply create a new instance of the form, modify its text and show it?

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement? It appears from the above that your trying to run a form in a thread separate from the main thread. Any gui/user interaction through forms should be on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
namespace UIThreadMarshalling {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                var tt = new ThreadTest();
                ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(tt.StartUiThread);
                Thread t = new Thread(ts);
                t.Name = "UI Thread";
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
        }

    }

 public class ThreadTest {
        Form _form;
        public ThreadTest() {
        }

     public void StartUiThread()
     {
        using (Form1 _form = new Form1())
        {
            Application.Run(_form);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm activating the thread after i click a button in another form.

Comment: nothing to stop you from putting the code shown here in Main in a button click event.

Comment: i will put the code i wrote in a new answer. please tell me if i did ok

Comment: public void Send(string body, string name)
        {

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(method));
            t.Start();
}

public void method()
        {
            form2.Text = name_form;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form2(value_label));
            
        }